# Angular:4 Is there any way to use angularjs module into angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am using malhar-angular-dashboard which is meant for AngularJS but I want to use this module in an Angular 4 web-app, I'm trying different ways to do this but still no luck.

I want to add draggable cards dashboard.

https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard

Many Thanks

Comment: AngularJS and Angular 4 are very different and generally non-compatible

Comment: checkout this link, it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950137/use-angularjs-directive-in-angular-component