# Use AngularJS directive in Angular Component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, upgrade, hybrid

I'm trying to upgrade an angularjs directive to use it my angular component.  I've gotten the hybrid (ng1 + ng2) environment to work.  I can also inject angularjs services in angular and use them in angular components (I actually got this working even with angularjs 1.4.x).

Now I'm trying to use an existing angularjs directive in angular, but not working.

For reference, are some snippets of my codes.

**[index.html] (my-app is the Angular 4 root component)**

```
...
<body>
    <div class="banner">Angular Migration</div>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
...
</body>
...
```

**[main.ts] (bootstrapping code)**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  let upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['sampleApp']);
  platformRef.injector.get(Router).initialNavigation();
});
```

**[app.module.ts] (Angular 4 module)**

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { RouterModule, Routes, UrlHandlingStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { HybridUrlHandlingStrategy } from './hybridUrlHandlingStrategy';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([], { useHash: true, initialNavigation: false })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: HybridUrlHandlingStrategy },
    { provide: 'appService', useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('appService'), deps: ['$injector'] },
    { provide: 'mdToHtml', useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('mdToHtml'), deps: ['$injector'] }
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]    
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() { }
}
```

**[app.component.ts] (Angular 4 component)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div ng-view></div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**[app.js] (AngularJs app)**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sampleApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'app.components.services.appService'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({
        template: ''
      });
  });
```

**[myStars.js] (AngularJs directive)**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.components.directives.myStars', [])
.controller('MyStarsCtrl', function() {
  console.log("**** in MyStarsCtrl ")
})
.component('myStars', {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    count: '=count'
  },
  template: '<div>***** M Y   S T A R S *****</div>'
});
```

**[myStars.ts] (an attempt to migrate myStars directive to Angular 4)**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Directive({
  selector: 'my-stars'
})
export class MyStarsDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  @Input() count: number;
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<number>;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('myStars', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

**[test.module.ts] (Angular 4 test module)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

// importing the new MyStarsDirective)
import { MyStarsDirective } from '../../../components/directives/myStars/myStars';

const thisRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'test/:id',
        component: TestComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        MyStarsDirective, // <<<< adding directive here
    ],
    providers: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(thisRoute)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class TestModule {}
```

**[test.component.ts] (Angular 4 test component)**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HybridUrlHandlingStrategy } from '../../../hybridUrlHandlingStrategy';
import { MyStarsDirective } from '../../../components/directives/myStars/myStars';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  routeParams: any
  myService: any
  mdToHtml: any

  constructor(
    @Inject('myService') myService: any,
    @Inject('mdToHtml') mdToHtml: (str: string) => string,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.myService = myService;
    this.mdToHtml = mdToHtml;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeParams = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log("params", params['groupId'])
...
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeParams.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**[test.component.html] (Angular 4 html)**

```
...
<my-stars></my-stars>      <!-- <<<< using directive here -->
...
```

Note: I've also upgrade angularjs version to 1.5 just to make this hybrid app works.

Here's the error when I browser the test component page:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using $scope on your code?

Comment: @BrunoPoeta I have $scope in angularjs code, but no where in the upgraded component.

Comment: It's weird because the thrown error by zone.js says that you have it somewhere on your component.

Comment: @BrunoPoeta Someone said that it could be the way I bootstrap the two frameworks.

Comment: @BrunoPoeta Btw, I do have $scope in my other angularjs directives and controllers.  I haven't attempted to migrate or upgrade them yet.  Does that matter?

Comment: @BrunoPoeta Got it to work.  Your question made me really focus on $scope and I finally found the answer at  this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14993.  See gkalpak comment on March 10.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone interested, here's the solution to this error.

**[test.module.ts] (Angular 4 test module)**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

// importing the new MyStarsDirective)
import { MyStarsDirective } from '../../../components/directives/myStars/myStars';

const thisRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'test/:id',
        component: TestComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        MyStarsDirective, // <<<< adding directive here
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: '$scope',
            useFactory: i => i.get('$rootScope'),
            deps: ['$injector']
        }, // <<<< added this section to fix the No provider for $scope error
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(thisRoute)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class TestModule {}
```

I found the answer in this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14993 (inspired by BrunoPoeta)
See comment by gkalpak on March 10.

Now let's see if I can upgrade a regular directive and use 1.4.x.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad I could help you, Will!

Comment: saved me a ton of time, thanks. I spent couple of days trying to figure out a fix until I found this answer